# Eclipse Photon 4.8 Spring IDE Downloading and Installing Issue

Tags: spring, eclipse

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: Spring IDE Roo Support 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE) Software currently installed: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.14.0.v20180611-0500 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.14.0.v20180611-0500) Only one of the following can be installed at once: Java Code Manipulation Functionality 1.5.0.v20130605-1748 (org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation 1.5.0.v20130605-1748) Java Code Manipulation Functionality 1.10.0.v20180323-0650 (org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation 1.10.0.v20180323-0650) Java Code Manipulation Functionality 1.9.50.v20170920-1015 (org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation 1.9.50.v20170920-1015) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: AspectJ Development Tools 2.2.4.e44x-20150610-1600 (org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.2.4.e44x-20150610-1600) To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ajdt.ui [2.2.4.e44x-20150610-1600,2.2.4.e44x-20150610-1600] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: AspectJ Development Tools UI 2.2.4.e44x-20150610-1600 (org.eclipse.ajdt.ui 2.2.4.e44x-20150610-1600) To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation [1.3.0,1.7.0) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.14.0.v20180611-0500 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.14.0.v20180611-0500) To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation [1.10.0.v20180323-0650,1.10.0.v20180323-0650] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Spring IDE Roo Support 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE) To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse require Eclipse 2019-03 as the base platform. If you want to instal the old Spring Tool Suite 3 package instead into an Eclipse 4.8 platform, you could use this update site using the "Install New Software" dialog: https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.8/ - it serves the STS 3.9.7 release, which is the last one compatible with Eclipse 4.8.

Reference Link :https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse-luna-44/metrics